# jQuery .html() not triggering 'select2:select' function on select2

Tags: jquery

i have this form with two select inputs

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('reg_id') ? ' has-error has-danger' : '' }}">
  <label for="reg_id">Region : </label>                                         
  <select style="width:100%;" class="form-control" name="reg_id" id="drp_reg">
     <option value="0">Please Select</option>
      @if(isset($regions))
        @foreach($regions as $region)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
          <option value="{{$region->id}}">{{$region->reg_name}}</option>                                                    
        @endforeach
      @endif
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('prov_id') ? ' has-error has-danger' : '' }}" id="provSelect">

   <label for="prov_id">Province : </label>                                         
   <select style="width:100%;" class="form-control" name="prov_id" id="drp_prov">
     <option value="0">Please Select</option>
      @if(isset($provinces))
         @foreach($provinces as $province)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
           <option value="{{$province->id}}">{{$province->prov_name}}</option>                                                    
         @endforeach
      @endif
   </select>

</div>
```

when the region select is changed i change the values of province select by sending ajax request.

**jQuery:**

```
 $('#drp_reg').on('select2:select', function (e) { // when select region is changed..

   let regId = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
       url: "{{URL::to('/')}}/get-province-by-region",
       method: "POST",
       data: {
          regId: regId,
          action: 'add'
      },
      success: function(data)
      {
          $('#provSelect').html(data);
          $('#drp_prov').select2();
      }
   });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function get_province_by_region(Request $request)
{
   if ($request->action == 'add') {

       $reg_id = $request->regId;
       $provinces=Probinsya::_getProvincesForDropdownByRegion($reg_id);
       $data = view('barangays/province_select', ['provinces' => $provinces])->render();

   } 

   return $data;
}
```

My problem is , im not triggereing the 'select2:select' on the province select

```
$('#drp_prov').on('select2:select', function (e) { // when select province is changed..
   let provId = $(this).val() 
   console.log(provId) // i got no result
});
```

Comment: Do you have to use select2 or can you just do $('#drp_reg').on('change', function...

Comment: yes i need to use select2 because i have many province and region to select